# Reality of field quantization

Tags: fourier-transform, quantum-optics, complex-numbers, second-quantization

In the quantization of the electromagnetic field (using the "second quantization" method), one says that the transverse vector potential must be

$$A(r,t)=\sum_k (\alpha_k e^{i \vec{k}  \vec{r}}+\alpha_{-k}^* e^{-i \vec{k}  \vec{r}})$$

Having two terms in order to be real.

But why the second $\alpha$ has that $-k$? Shouldnt be enough to be its complex conjugate? I mean, any complex number plus its conjugate gives a real number.

I dont get it, every book or article I read (for example this one on the end of page 3: https://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/wysin/notes/quantumEM.pdf) starts to wander how to make the field real, arriving to the obvious conclussion that: 
$$
\operatorname{something}+\operatorname{something}^*=2 \operatorname{Re}(\operatorname{something}). 
$$

Im missing something?

Comment: One does? Not that $\alpha^*_k=\alpha_{-k}$?

Comment: You are misreading.  Even in the reference which you provide, the second operator (the one with the subscript $-k$)is not conjugated.

Answer (score 1):

The quirkiness comes from the Fourier transform. The quantization expression is essentially a Fourier transform. It turns out that the Fourier transform of a real function is not a real function anymore. The symmetry also plays a role. If the function is real and symmetric [$f(-x)=f(x)$], then the spectrum is also real and symmetric. However, if the function is real and anti-symmetric [$f(-x)=-f(x)$], then its spectrum is imaginary and anti-symmetric. Combining these two observation, one finds that if $f(x)$ is a general real function, then 
$$ F^*(a) = F(-a) , $$
where $F(a)$ is the spectrum of $f(x)$.